# Change the site slogan on certain pages

Tags: 8, theming

I have a Drupal 8 site with a content type called **Landing Page**.  I'm using the bootstrap theme and I have the block showing the brand info (including site slogan) in the navbar.

I want some of the landing pages to have a different site slogan (shown in the navbar).  How can I do that?

**What I tried**

I thought of adding a text field **custom site slogan** to my **Landing Page** content type and then using a twig template (content type node template) to show the slogan, but the slogan is printed in the header, and the template comes after that.

I could also make a different branding block for each page I need to change the slogan on and manually change the text in a twig template, but that seems like a very horrible, labor intensive way to do it.

Comment: Agree having a field on the content type to override the slogan text, then use `preprocess_node()` to check if the field has value and replace the slogan from the site block. Or if the alternate slogan is the same for all changed pages, use a `boolean` field on the content type? Off the top of my head, seems like you'll need some flag somewhere on the content type level...

Comment: Further, if you do make a field on the content type, I would suggest a select field that can be reused and updated. Have a default slogan, then a list of alternatives. This field could then be reused with its logic on any node. Just to future proof if you're going to do all that work.

Comment: You could use `HOOK_preprocess_block` and in there check for node pages with `$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');`

Comment: Could `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');` be translated in OOP to 50 out of 500 nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the hint from @Hudri, here's what I did.

In **mycustomtheme.theme**:

```
function MYCUSTOMTHEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['configuration']['id'] === 'MYMODULE_site_branding_nolinks_block') {
    $site_config = \Drupal::config('system.site');
    $vars['site_slogan'] = $site_config->get('slogan');
    $vars['site_name'] = $site_config->get('name');
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $type = $node->getType();
      // For landing pages, set the site slogan to the value of the slogan field.
      if ($type === 'landingpage') {
        $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($node->id());
        $slogan_field = $node->get('field_slogan')->getValue();
        $slogan_field = $slogan_field[0]['value'];
        $vars['site_slogan'] = $slogan_field;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, we're not done yet, because the block (provided by my custom module) is cached the same for every page; it needs to be cached per URL, since it might be different for each landing page.

To fix that, in **mymodule/src/Plugins/Blocks/myBlock.php**, add this code:

```
  // Caching must be added here:
  // https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223376/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-cache-contexts-on-custom-blocks
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return Cache::mergeContexts(parent::getCacheContexts(), ['url.path', 'url.query_args']);
  }
```

Comment: I'd bet you can simply set the caching in the block prepo function, too. `$vars['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'url';`.

Comment: @leymannx That did not work for me, see this issue: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223376/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-cache-contexts-on-custom-blocks