# Views field cache tags does not invalidate the views cache

Tags: views, 8

I've implemented `CacheableDependencyInterface` on my ViewsField plugin.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return ['arbitrary_tag'];
  }
```

I can see the tag on the HEADER and the View configuration object.

However, when that tag is invalidated, the View is not updated.

I've also tried using adding cache tags to the `render` method:

```
return [
  '#markup' => $message,
  '#cache' => [
    'tags' => ['my_list'],
  ],
];
```

Both to the Views field, but also tried directly on the View element using `hook_views_pre_view`

While debugging, I've made sure to try invalidate that specific tag:

```
Cache::invalidateTags(['my_list']);
```

While debugging further it seems like that the ResultRow values are still cached after clearing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are Views plugins which use CacheableDependencyInterface, I'm not sure it is the right way for a field plugin, because a field renders content and a cache tag of rendered content belongs in the render array.

This was discussed in [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288881/problem-setting-user-specific-cache-tags-on-custom-block-with-user-context) for block plugins. Don't know if this here or in the other issues for blocks is a core issues, because you can see in both core modules the effort to collect plugin cacheable metadata, or Drupal assumes, that all render arrays fulfill the requirements outlined in [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays):

> "It is of the utmost importance that you inform the Render API of the
>   cacheability of a render array"

Anyways, an easy fix is to put the cache tag in the rendered output of the field.

Comment: I was a bit to fast on the Approve here, it doesn't actually seem to help to put the cache tags on the rendered output.

Comment: While debugging further, it looks like the ResultRow values are still the same, but the Views rendering gets rebuilt.

Comment: When I put your markup with the cache tag in a field plugin the cached result row contains the tag `my_list`.

Comment: Thanks so much 4uk4! I struggled with a ViewsField plugin which was called for a node that has been deleted. Adding the CacheableDependencyInterface did not work, but repeating the cache tags in the render array did. Like: `$build['#cache']['tags'] = ['node_list'];`